# C++ - What does the 'dot' operator means when used in std::cin.getline()?

Tags: c++

I'm used to program in Python, and since in Python, all are objects, it is totally acceptable when at the end of a variable, a `.` operator is used to access the `method` of a `class`. But in C++, let say for something like `std::cin.getline()`, is this some kind of accessing the member function of `cin`?

Is `cin` some kind of a `class` or a `struct`?

Comment: Did you try reading some documentation of `std::cin` to find out what it is?

Comment: I am also still kind of confuse with all of the syntax of C++ and how it actually works, so, I just think that by asking here, it would be better and more time saving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you type:

```
#include <iostream>
```

the corresponding headerfile is inserted there. One line of this file reads

```
extern istream cin;
```

So as you see you have an object of type *istream* accessable from anywhere in the file with the include statement.

So your guess that cin is an instance of a class was right and the dot operator calls the getline method of that object/class.

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/

Answer (score 4):

`cin` is indeed an instance of the class `std::istream`.

Answer (score 2):

```
std
```

Is the `namespace`

```
cin
```

Is an object from the `istream` class

```
getline
```

Is a method from the `cin` class.

Comment: `cin` is not a class, it's a (global) variable. It is an instance of a class, though.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Thanks